# Powerpoint - deleting images - the image with relationship ID rId23 was not found in file

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Powerpoint has gone into the unfortunate habit of deleting images from presentations, replacing them with red crosses and the text "the image with relationship ID rId23 was not found in file". this is causing me hours of additional work. there is some documentation on this on the internet (e.g. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-powerpoint/powerpoint-2013-images-in-presentation-disappear/dbacd4f2-a514-4f67-b4d9-c3c33010eb3e) although the presceibed solution is unclear to me.

i tried to disable hardware acceleration - but unfortunately the ability to change advanced display settings (control panel / screen resolution / advanced settings / troubleshoot) is greyed out and not accessible for me. I am running 64bit Windows 7 with an intel graphics card

Does anyone have suggestions on how to prevent this / fix this bug?

Comment: Are you including the actual image or a *link* to the image? When you get the error, have you tried putting the file containing the image in the same folder as the PPT file?

Comment: Same issue here, nasty bug, did you try Microsoft Update? I'd be curious to know what patches solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's an incredibly long thread (some 42 pages of stuff). The short version is more or less:

Right off:

Don't open files into PPT from DropBox, OneDrive or any other similar locations.
Copy them to your hard drive, in a folder that is NOT synched, and open/save there.

Next:

Apply available updates to PowerPoint.  You don't mention which version of PPT you have; specific instructions for this will vary.  MS may not have totally eliminated this problem, but they've definitely got it on the run.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is, sometimes people "drag and drop" the image directly from Internet browser into Power Point, which will cause the broken image behavior.

I usually right-click to save the Internet image file to local hard disk.

Then, to properly insert image, from top menu, select Insert->Picture.